# Having problems with String toLowerCase

Tags: java, string, lowercase, tolower

I am having troubles with converting to lower case from a string. I need to be able to accept a multitude of case combinations to ensure that it works regardless of how the user inputs the 'priority' string.

Here is my enqueue method

```
public void enqueue(T element, String priority){
    priority = priority.toLowerCase();
    if (priority == "high"){
        prioritiesArr[0].add(prioritiesArr[0].count, element);
    }
    else if (priority == "medium"){
        prioritiesArr[1].add(prioritiesArr[1].count, element);
    }
    else if (priority == "low"){
        prioritiesArr[2].add(prioritiesArr[2].count, element);
    }
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid priority option");

    System.out.println("added " + element + " with priority " + priority );
}
```

And when the tester calls

```
test.enqueue(1, "High");
```

I get the IllegalArgumentException. The problem is that when I did some print debugging, the string was, in fact, lowercase, but when I go to compare it to the lowercase version in `enqueue` it appears that it does not have the same value.

Is there some kind of comparison problem? Please give me a hand! Thanks

Comment: I also found that in this particular application, `String.equalsIgnoreCase` is very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `String.equals()` for comparison using Strings.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something along those lines. Looking at this screen for hours is getting to me apparently.